# "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethod" error while making a model in Apache Spark in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I am trying to make a model using spark scala to predict on my label but,my IDE shows me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.ml.regression.LinearRegression.fit(Lorg/apache/spark/sql/Dataset;)Lorg/apache/spark/ml/PredictionModel;
```

Here is my TrainingDF dataframe that I want to make a model on it:

```
+--------------------+-----+
|            features|label|
+--------------------+-----+
|[1.497325796E9,19...|   19|
|[1.497325796E9,19...|   19|
|[1.497325796E9,19...|   19|
|[1.497325796E9,10...|   10|
|[1.497325796E9,10...|   10|
|[1.497325796E9,10...|   10|
|[1.497325796E9,10...|   10|
|[1.497325796E9,10...|   10|
+--------------------+-----+
```

The error is on val `model1=lir.fit(TrainingDF)` code and I completely puzzled about this error. The input of my fit function is dataframe. Here is my code:

```
        val final_df = Dataframe.withColumn(
          "features",
          toVec4(
            // casting into Timestamp to parse the string, and then into Int
            $"time_stamp_0".cast(TimestampType).cast(IntegerType),
            $"count",
            $"sender_ip_1",
            $"receiver_ip_2"
          )
        ).withColumn("label", (Dataframe("count"))).select("features", "label")

        final_df.show()

        val trainingTest = final_df.randomSplit(Array(0.3, 0.7))
        val TrainingDF = trainingTest(0).toDF()
        val TestingDF=trainingTest(1).toDF()
        TrainingDF.show()
        TestingDF.show()
```

Until this part everything works perfectly. However the TrainingDF dataframe cannot be accepted by `lir.fit`.

```
 ///lets create our liner regression
    val lir= new LinearRegression()
    .setRegParam(0.3)
    .setElasticNetParam(0.8)
    .setMaxIter(100)
    .setTol(1E-6)


    //////make model -> Error is here
    val model1=lir.fit(TrainingDF)

  }
}
```

Also here is my dependencies in my build.sbt file:

```
name := "untitled"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

retrieveManaged := true

resolvers += "Typesafe Repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

resolvers += "MapR Repository" at "http://repository.mapr.com/maven/"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.6.1",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.1.1",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % "1.6.1",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.6.1",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka" % "1.6.1",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-flume" % "1.6.1",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "1.6.1",
  "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-api" % "2.5",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.3.4",
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.3.3",
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" % "jackson-module-scala_2.10" % "2.3.3",
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.31",
  "com.github.scopt" %% "scopt" % "3.4.0", //OptinsParser
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.1" % "test",
  "com.holdenkarau" %% "spark-testing-base" % "0.0.1" % "test"

)
```

I should mention that I use IntelliJ IDEA. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of this problem is likely a discrepancy between the versions of the Spark libraries you're using. Make sure you're using the same versions for `spark-core` and `spark-mllib`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But both of them are 1.6.1. I have updated the question and added the independencies to it.

Comment: Maybe I should use newer version of independencies. Yes?

Comment: You're using `spark-sql` 2.1.1, so I assume you're able to use the 2.1.1 versions of the other Spark libraries as well. Upgrade to 2.1.1 and update your Scala version to 2.11.11.

Comment: I will test it and inform you, Thanks. :)

Comment: Use `import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.{Vector, Vectors}` instead of `import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{Vector, Vectors}`.

Comment: Thanks it works successfully. But in my intellij idea the code for making model is pointed by red under line. Anyway, it dose't effect on the output.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to multiple version of spark dependencies. Try using

```
 "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.1",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.1.1",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % "2.1.1",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "2.1.1",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka" % "2.1.1",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-flume" % "2.1.1",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "2.1.1",
  "org.apache.logging.log4j" % "log4j-api" % "2.5",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.3.4",
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.3.3",
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" % "jackson-module-scala_2.10" % "2.3.3",
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.31",
  "com.github.scopt" %% "scopt" % "3.4.0", //OptinsParser
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.1" % "test",
  "com.holdenkarau" %% "spark-testing-base" % "0.0.1" % "test"
```

I also suggest to update the scala version.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have done that, but the error is still exist! :( Even I updated the version of scala!